# ballerina grpc how to create a client and server

Tags: ballerina

In this problem, we wish to design and build components of an assessment management system using gRPC. The system has three user profiles: learner, administrator and assessor. Note that each user should have a unique identifier in the system. A learner registers for courses, submits assignments for each assessment of each course he/she registered for, and finally checks his/her result. An administrator adds new courses and sets the number of assessments for each course and the assessment weights. He/she also assigns assessors to each course. Finally, an assessor allocated for a course assesses the assignments submitted.
In short, we have the following operations:
• create_courses, where an administrator creates several courses, defines the number of assignments for each course and sets the weight for each assignment. This operation returns the code for each created course. It is bidirectional streaming;
• assign_courses, where an administrator assigns each created course to an assessor;
• create_users, where several users, each with a specific profile, are created. The users are streamed to the server, and the response is returned once the operation completes;
• submit_assignments, where a learner submits one or several assignments for one or multiple courses he/she registered for. The assignments are streamed to the server, and the response is received once the operation completes;
• request_assignments, where an assessor requests submitted assignments for a course he/she has been allocated. Note that an assignment can be marked only once. The function should stream back all assignments that have not been marked yet;
• submit_marks, where an assessor submits the marks for assignments;
• register, where a learner registers for one or several courses. All the courses are streamed to the server, and the result is returned once the operation
completes;
1

```
Your task is to define a protocol buffer contract with the remote functions and implement both the client and the server in the Ballerina Language.
Assessment Criteria
We will follow the criteria below to assess this problem:
• Definition of the remote interface in Protocol Buffer. (25%)
• Implementation of the gRPC client in the Ballerina language. (25%)
• Implementation of the gRPC server and server-side logic in response to
the remote invocations in the Ballerina Language. (50%) Problem 2
Marks: 20/100
Problem
We wish to query and update COVID-19 statistics using a GraphQL API in this problem. The example below shows a single statistic with the date, the region, and the total number of deaths, confirmed_cases, recoveries and tested cases.
{
}
An update changes the statistics to the latest for a given region, while a query returns the latest statistics for that region.
Your task is to write a Graphql service in the Ballerina Language to query and update the COVID-19 statistics.
Assessment criteria
• Correct definition of the required object types. (15%)
• Correct Implementation of the service. (60%)
• Correct business logic in the API implementation. (25%)
"date"": "12/09/2021", "region": "Khomas", "deaths": 39, "confirmed_cases": 465, "recoveries": 67, "tested": 1200
Problem 3
Marks: 30/100
2

Problem
This problem focuses on a Restful API to manage a student record. A student is defined by a student number, a name, an email address and the courses the student took. For each course, there is the course code, the weights of the assessments in the course and the marks awarded for each assessment. The API should fulfil the following functions:
• Create a new student;
• Update student details;
• Update student’s course details; • lookup a single student;
• fetch all students;
• delete a student.
Note that the student number should serve as a unique identifier for a student. Your task is to define the API following the OpenAPI standard and implement
the client and service in the Ballerina language.
Evaluation criteria
We will follow the criteria below to assess this problem:
• A correct description of the API in OpenAPI. (40%)
• Implementation of the restful client and service in the Ballerina language.
(50%)
• Quality of design and implementation. (10%)
Submission Instructions
• This assignment is to be completed by groups of at most two students each.
• For each group, a repository should be created on Gitlab. The repository should have all group members set up as contributors.
• The submission date is Sunday, September 25 2022, at midnight. Please note that commits after that deadline will not be accepted. Therefore, a submission will be assessed based on the clone of the repository at the deadline.
• Any group that fails to submit on time will be awarded the mark 0.
• Although this is a group project, each member will receive a mark that reflects his/her contribution to the project. Each group member will be allowed to highlight his/her contribution during the presentation of the project. More particularly, if a student’s username does not appear in the commit log of the group repository, that student will be assumed not to
have contributed to the project and thus be awarded the mark 0.
• Each group is expected to present its project after the submission deadline.
3

• There should be no assumption about the execution environment of your code. It could be run using a specific framework or on the command line. • In the case of plagiarism (groups copying from each other or submissions
copied from the Internet), all submissions involved will be awarded the mark 0, and each student will receive a warning.
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the steps to create a gRPC client and server in the Ballerina docs[1].

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/grpc-simple/

Answer (score 0):

Adding few more resources related to Ballerina gRPC client and server.

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/write-a-grpc-service-with-ballerina/

[2] https://medium.com/ballerina-techblog/introduction-to-grpc-on-ballerina-7819d98c4e2b